# Permissions in WordPress on VPS

Tags: wordpress, apache, vps, chmod

I'm currently working on site for client. I installed Wordfence and it is showing problem with writing (root and plugin folder). I manage to partly solve problem with CHMOD 777, all other folders are 775 and files 644 (it was set like that).

I of course don't want to have anything with permissions 777. It should be VPS with Apache. Wordfence information is showing "Process owner" as "www-data". I found it could be problem with user/group setting. Can it be solved by this?

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /data/home/projects/website.cz/wordpress/
```

I don't have too much experience with servers so I appreciate some insight ;)

Answer (score 0):

chmod 777 means making the file readable, writable and executable by everyone

the first digit is for user second is for groups and third is for others

4 means read 2 means write and 1 means execute

777 means

```
4+2+1 = read + write + execute user
4+2+1 = read + write + execute group
4+2+1 = read + write + execute other
```

Comment: I know. But in WP installation shouldn't be any folder set to 777. So it's only temporary fix for issue. I'm finding solution to repair it in way that Wordfence will be able to write with recommended 755. I guess it's Apache issue.